# Slow Scan TV Documentation

Tags: video-processing

I am looking for information on how to decode [slow scan TV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-scan_television) signals, which is a method of transmitting static images using everyday FM radio.

I have seen software but I don't understand how to start. Any open source would help as well. To very specific I want to know how to decode the sound into an image.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on your question somewhat so that we understand what you know and what you don't know. This question in your current form lacks clarity. Give some background on what you're trying to do. What have you read so far? What do you not understand? The better your question is the better the answers will be.

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the Wikipedia page that you linked to in your question you'll see at least one open source SSTV decoder, QSSTV: http://users.telenet.be/on4qz/ - you could start by looking at the source code for this in order to get some ideas.

Comment: Thank you Paul. Someone linked it for me. I will be checking that out to see if it is what I am looking for.